# Adding an automatically updating column in a point layer with information from another point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have 2 point data layers.  Point A layer is for capturing features in the field and point B layer contains postcode data.  What I am trying to achieve is when a point feature is created in point A layer it automatically updates a column in point A layer with the nearest postcode from point B layer. Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

**QGIS 3.0+**

Perhaps you can use `Default` setting in the Layer Widgets, along with the [refFunctions](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin.

Below is an example of a new layer, which has a `soil` layer to copy the soil information from `meuse` point layer.

You will see **Default value** is set to `geomnearest('meuse_point_32632', 'soil')` which means it copies the `soil` field from nearest point in the `meuse_point_32632` layer.

[image]

Then, you will get the `soil` data is copied to your new layer while digitizing to add points.

[image]

---

**QGIS 2.18**

You can use [AutoFields](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) plugin along with the [refFunctions](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin.

In the AutoFields window, select `Custom Expression` and set `geomnearest('other_point_layer', 'target_field')`.

Detailed information can be found at [AutoFields plygin](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/333-autofields-plugin-for-qgis) website.

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS 3.x you can also try using the following expression in the *Default value* section of the attributes form shown in Kazuhito's reply. Replace `'Point B'` with the name of your Point B layer and `"postcode"` with your Point B postcode field respectively.

If you want it to update every time you edit the existing Point A layer data, then enable 'Apply default value on update' as well.

```
aggregate('Point B','concatenate',"postcode",
           intersects(closest_point(aggregate('Point B','collect',$geometry),
                                    geometry(@parent)),
                      $geometry))
```

What this does is aggregate values from another layer (`"postcode"` values from the `Point B` layer) and filter them using a sort of 'nearest neighbour' join.

The filter looks for the closest point on your Point B layer (which is aggregated using `collect`), to your Point A layer (`geometry(@parent)` as we are now in aggregate-land), and then checks that *that* point intersects with the Point B geometry. In other words, *"filter the features that are the closest to your Point A geometry"*.

(Because these are both point layers, you could probably using `within()` instead of `intersects()` if you wanted to.)

Result:

[image]

---

### Bonus

As an aside, I originally misread your original question as a point to polygon question and came up with an interesting finding: a similar approach works, but you need to buffer the polygon by the very tiniest amount or you will occasionally get some `closest_point()` results that are disjoint from the polygon layer. I believe this has to do with how QGIS renders the point geometries; there is some rounding involve.

```
aggregate('Polygon','concatenate',"name",
           intersects(closest_point(aggregate('Polygon','collect',$geometry),
                                    geometry(@parent)),
                      buffer($geometry,0.000000000001)))
```

Result (points in red are the `closest_point()` results styled using geometry generator):

[image]